# Can't play mp4 converted file - JavaFX 2.1

Tags: video, media-player, javafx-2, converters

I have converted my `.mov` video to `.mp4`, but when I play the video in my javafx application, it doesn't work, I can hear the audio of the video file but without pictures ! maybe the .mp4 is not in the right codec! any idea or solution?

**UPDATE**

With the same code I have played another mp4 video, in the same conditions (plateforme, JFX Version, ...), so I'm concluding that I have problem with this mp4 converted file, ie the software that I'm using to convert the mov file doesn't generate the approriat mp4 format that is supported by JFX 2.1.

Comment: What OS are you using?  What codec are you using?  Is the codec h.264? Is the video playable with JavaFX 2.2?

Comment: I'm using xp and I have installed divx. For the codec, I'm trying to convert the video to H264 and I don't know if I have succeeded to do that correctly. for JavaFX 2.2, I don't know because I'm using 2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code sample demonstrates playing an h.264 encoded mp4 video in JavaFX.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.media.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/** plays an mp4 video in JavaFX 2.1+ */
public class OnlineVideoPlayer extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    final Label status = new Label("Init");
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = createMediaPlayer(
      "http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4", 
      status
    );
    VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    layout.getChildren().addAll(new MediaView(mediaPlayer), status);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(layout, 500, 300, Color.CORNSILK));
    stage.show();
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
      mediaPlayer.play();
    }  
  }

  /** 
   * creates a media player using a url to the media
   * and tracks the status of playing the media via the status label 
   */
  private MediaPlayer createMediaPlayer(final String url, final Label status) {
    Media hit = new Media(url);
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
    mediaPlayer.setOnError(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        status.setText("Error");
      }
    });
    mediaPlayer.setOnPlaying(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        status.setText("Playing: " + url);
      }
    });
    mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        status.setText("Done");
      }
    });
    return mediaPlayer;
  }
}
```

Sample program output: (JavaFX 8u72, OS X 10.9.5).
[image: barbie]
[image: woody]

Comment: I tried the code but keep getting media audio format unsupported errors. The video the example uses is no longer there, so I'm trying file from here without luck: http://www.sample-videos.com/

Comment: I updated my answer to use a new video link and it played back fine.

Comment: @jewelsea Is there anything I can do if the video is .mp4 but encoded in MPEG4?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your .mp4 file is encoded in H264. MPEG4 does not work.