# shows an error when i run my javafx application

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

i am trying to create a videoplayer with javafx, but when I try to run the class, it shows some error

```
public class MoviePlayer extends Application{


public static void main (String [] args){
launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Group root = new Group();       
    Media media = new Media("C:\\Users\\goldAnthony\\Videos\\Whistle.mp4");

    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
    MediaView view = new MediaView(player);

    root.getChildren().add(view);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400, Color.BLACK);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    player.play();
}
```

this is the error it shows

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Player.VideoPlayer2
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

some i have asked says the code works fine, i dont really know what seems to be the problem because it gives this error above

Comment: Are you use netbeansIDE.....

Comment: most probably you need to set main class in project properties

Comment: You are trying to run videoplater2, and not the main class shown in the code

Comment: You may try this link its working fine.

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322983/mp4-unsupported-in-javafx