# JavaFX loop playing .mp4 local video file

Tags: java, video, javafx, javafx-2, mp4

I've used code sample provided by [jewelsea code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322983/mp4-unsupported-in-javafx) and just change it a bit to INDEFINITE loop play local .mp4 file that I downloaded from [here](http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/http-mp4.htm) (Test1):

```
File file = new File("/Users/developer/H264_test1_Talkinghead_mp4_480x360.mp4");
VID_URL = file.toURI().toString();
```

In comparison I've loop played Oracle .flv file that I downloaded from [here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv) using same code.
After about 2-3 min of .mp4 file loop play application freezes and I had to force quit it, while .flv file loop play is still running with no problems.

I am using jdk-7u71-macosx-x64 in Eclipse Luna IDE on OS X Mavericks.
Maybe this is OS X - JavaFX related problem, but I sincerely doubt that. My guess is that JavaFX have a problem with .mp4 video loop play.

If you had similar experiences, please advise.
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a bug only developers can address. I'd suggest to file it at https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/ and provide erroneous mp4.

Comment: I ran the .mp4 in a loop for 15 minutes on OS X 10.9 with JavaFX 8u31 and had no issues.  I suggest you [update to Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and try again.

Comment: Thanks for reply but unfortunately I am limited to Java EE 7 by project setup, though I would like to use Java 8, especially with e(fx)clipse plugin :(

Comment: Java EE 7 can run on Java SE 8. Using Java SE 7 is not advisable because public updates for it [stop next month](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html). There are also many bugs in JavaFX 7 which are fixed in Java 8 but will never be fixed in Java 7.