# How to embed a 10 second MP4 video in java GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, video, mp4

I've looked up multiple options for embedding a MP4 video into my GUI. I seen many people advise against using swing because it's old. I've done many GUI's with adding image icons and such but never tried embedding a MP4 video until now. Is there a simple way to embed my MP4 video into my GUI such as how Image Icons are added? Also is there a method that will keep this video on replay until the application closes? such as a video.repeat(true); or something of that nature? Thanks for all the help ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if/how it is possible in pure Swing, but you can embed a JavaFX MediaPlayer in your Swing application, see details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16326393/1149528 or here: [Can't play mp4 converted file - JavaFX 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749145/cant-play-mp4-converted-file-javafx-2-1)